# Local Storage does not works in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, local-storage

I'm using Angular's Local Storage and it does not seems to work in IE. I need to clear the browser history every time to make it work. I'm testing in IE 10 and IE 11. Is there any other approach for the same ??

Comment: Why is there an angularjs tag here?

Comment: According to this: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage localStorage should be working in IE since version 8

Comment: Yeah it works..but as I said every time I need to clear the browsers history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bug demo:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XckcyREs2SUxTODQ/localStorage-test.html

This demo creates a LocalStorage test key named "testKey". It then starts a timer and increments "testKey" once per second.
You can open multiple instances of the demo. These other instances listen to storage events for updates to "testKey".
Try opening a few instances of the demo and see it works nicely.

Now try this. Starting fresh, open IE to a blank page. Open the demo and see the testKey increment. Next, open a 2nd instance (a listener page), and set its checkbox to delete testKey upon exit. Close this listener tab. This will delete testKey, but only momentarily. The original instance will just recreate it within one second and continue incrementing it. Wait at least one second to assure testKey is recreated. (just confirm in original instance that testKey is incrementing). Now open a new listener instance again and probably* discover it cannot find "testKey", so it creates another testKey and starts a 1sec interval timer to increment it. Finally, open several more demo instances and see how goofed up it is.

*probably. Usually the first time. Else repeat the listener experiment a few times until it happens.

Repro'd with IE10, IE11, and Win10


transcribed from [MS-Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1047049/storage-mutex-bug-after-deleting-localstorage-item-from-one-browsing-context-while-other-browsing-contexts-reference-that-same-storage-item)

Answer (score 0):

The storage event is supported everywhere the localStorage object is supported, which includes Internet Explorer 8. IE 8 does not support the W3C standard addEventListener (although that will finally be added in IE 9). Therefore, to hook the storage event, you’ll need to check which event mechanism the browser supports. (If you’ve done this before with other events, you can skip to the end of this section. Trapping the storage event works the same as every other event you’ve ever trapped. If you prefer to use jQuery or some other JavaScript library to register your event handlers, you can do that with the storage event, too.)

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onstorage", handle_storage);
};
```

The handle_storage callback function will be called with a StorageEvent object, except in Internet Explorer where the event object is stored in window.event.

```
function handle_storage(e) {
  if (!e) { e = window.event; }
}
```

from: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html